# C client-proxy-server file transfer sends only a portion of the file

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, network-programming, socks

I'm working on an application that sends files via proxy, but it only works for text files (like .txt, .c etc...) but only copies a portion of it. I also tried sending pictures but they also don't work.
I'm trying to send files via a 512 byte buffer.

Could anyone be kind enough to show me what is missing?
Also could anyone tell me what differs a socksv5 proxy from a normal hand-made username/password authentication?

this is the client code for when I'm sending a file

```
FILE *in = safe_fopen(in_filename, "r", 1);

    bzero(message,DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
    int fs_block;
    while((fs_block = fread(message, sizeof(char), DEFAULT_BUFLEN, in)) > 0){
        if(send(sock,message,fs_block,0)<0){
            printf("ERROR: Failed to send file %s. \n",in_filename);
            return 1;
        }
        bzero(message,DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
    }
    printf("OK FILE %s from client was sent! \n",in_filename);
```

this is the proxy that is forwarding it to the server

```
recv_msg(client_sock,message);

    make_server2(&server2);
    make_socket(&sock);

    if(make_connection(sock,server2)==1){
            return 0;
        }
    send_fun(sock,message);
```

and this is the server part where it recieves the file

```
FILE *out = safe_fopen(out_filename, "a" , 1);

    bzero(message,DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
    int fr_block = 0;   

    while(fr_block = recv(client_sock,message,DEFAULT_BUFLEN,0)){
        if(fr_block < 0){
            error("Error receiving file from client to server.\n");
        }
        int write_sz = fwrite(message,sizeof(char),fr_block,out);
        if(write_sz < fr_block){
            error("File write failed on server.\n");
        }
        else if(fr_block){
            return 1;
        }
        bzero(message,DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
    }
    printf("OK received from proxy_server! \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (fr_block)
    return 1:
```

The problem is here. In the normal case, `fr_block` will be the number of bytes read, i.e. positive, so this code will cause the copy loop to exit after the first successful iteration. Remove. Same for the similar test of `fs_block`.

Your error handling is also incorrect: if there is an error you should not continue with the body of the copy loop. It would be better to loop on `while ((fr_block = recv(...)) > 0)` and `while ((fs_block = fread(...)) > 0)` respectively, and check for errors after the loop. For example:

```
while((fr_block = recv(client_sock,message,DEFAULT_BUFLEN,0)) > 0){
    int write_sz = fwrite(message,sizeof(char),fr_block,out);
    if(write_sz < fr_block){
        perror("File write failed on server.\n");
        break;
    }
}
if(fr_block < 0){
    perror("Error receiving file from client to server.\n");
} else
```

As regards only working for text files, you should open in `"rb"` and `"wb"` mode.

NB The `bzero()` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: I removed the else if and implemented the rest but it still finishes after sending one buffer-worth of data. Could it be that the proxy isn't sending everything?

Comment: @Phaust: It depends who wrote the proxy.  If someone else wrote the proxy, that isn't the problem.  If you wrote it (or one of your fellow students wrote it), then it's conceivable that there's a problem there.  However, you should make sure your code is bullet-proof before casting aspersions at other code.

Comment: I wrote all three codes myself, the problem is I just started learning network programming a month ago and I'm still figuring out the sending/receiving parts, not so sure about them.

Comment: Did you remove the `return` along with the `else if`? And fix the other problems?

Comment: And you you have the same bugs in the proxy server?

Comment: Yeah. I fixed them now. I forgot to put the client sender into a for loop to send the rest of the packages, also works on any kind of file now.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in this code:

1. You open files in text mode, for binary "b" is required, use "rb" instead of "r" and "ab" instead of b. That's why you get garbage instead of image

   send() function is not guaranteed to send the whole buffer. That is  send(sock,message,fs_block,0) can actually send less than fs_block.  A number of bytes actually sent is returned. You have to call send() again for the rest of the data until the whole buffer is sent.

   You do not process "try again" errors from send() and recv() (EAGAIN, EINTR, etc - may be OS dependent).

   For proxy code, it's important how do you process socket closing, because you can still have some data in buffer then you receive connection termination. You need to flush the buffers before closing connection to second peer.

   Also, it's not clear from this code if sockets are in blocking or non-blocking mode. For non-blocking mode select()/poll() are required before send()/recv().

Answer (score -1):

The client sender should have gone like this:

```
    FILE *in = safe_fopen(in_filename, "r", 1);
    long int size = ftell(in);
    int n = size/DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    int i;
    int fs_block;
    for(i = 0; i<n+1; i++)
    {
        while((fs_block = fread(message,sizeof(char),DEFAULT_BUFLEN,in))>0){
            if(send(sock,message,fs_block,0)<0){
                printf("ERROR: Failed to send file %s. \n",in_filename);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("OK FILE %s from client was sent! \n",in_filename);

    fclose(in);

  close(sock);
```

Comment: I don't know why but it didn't. Alone it ony transfered a single buffer worth of data and finished the loop.